# how can i open the /data/data/com.android.email/EmailProviderBackup.db?

Tags: android

how can i open the /data/data/com.android.email/EmailProviderBackup.db ?
in my program.i set

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone"
```

and have platform sign.

```
public static final String EMAIL_BACKUPDB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.email/databases/EmailProvider.db";
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(EMAIL_BACKUPDB_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
it can open well.
```

but if i change the EMAIL_BACKUP_PATH like this:

```
public static final String EMAIL_BACKUPDB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.email/databases/EmailProviderBackup.db";
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(EMAIL_BACKUPDB_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

it doesn't works. the exception is :

```
02-21 12:25:33.852: E/SQLiteLog(10780): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (13) open(/data/data/com.android.email/databases/EmailProviderBackup.db) - 
02-21 12:25:33.859: E/SQLiteDatabase(10780): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.android.email/databases/EmailProviderBackup.db'.
02-21 12:25:33.859: E/SQLiteDatabase(10780): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

please help me! thanks!